# Вызов системного ping в Python и обработка его вывода

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Python 3.7, Win10. Есть функция, для пинга (взял из [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953462/pinging-servers-in-python)), которая обращается к системному ping. Но нужна не только оценка доступности хоста, но  еще нужно и время отклика получить (распарсить вывод).
Не могу понять:

1. почему вывод в int
2. как преобразовать в нормальную кодировку
3. как подавить этот вывод и преобразовать в str для дальнейшего разбора

Результат работы:

```
  ����� ����⠬� � google.com [216.58.215.78] � 32 ���⠬� ������:
�⢥� �� 216.58.215.78: �᫮ ����=32 �६�=27�� TTL=55

����⨪� Ping ��� 216.58.215.78:
    ����⮢: ��ࠢ���� = 1, ����祭� = 1, ����ﭮ = 0
    (0% �����)
�ਡ����⥫쭮� �६� �ਥ��-��।�� � ��:
    �������쭮� = 27�ᥪ, ���ᨬ��쭮� = 27 �ᥪ, �।��� = 27 �ᥪ
type con_out  <class 'int'>
s 0
encoded  b'0'
type:  <class 'int'>
getdefaultencoding:  utf-8
locale:  cp1251
stdout.encoding:  UTF-8
stdin.encoding:  UTF-8

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

Код:

```
    import sys
    import locale
    import subprocess
    import platform

    def ping(host):
    ping_str = "-n 1" if platform.system().lower() == "windows" else "-c 1"
    args = "ping " + " " + ping_str + " " + host
    con_out = subprocess.call(args)
    return con_out

ping_out = ping("google.com")
string = str(ping_out)
print('s', string)
print('encoded ', string.encode('utf8'))
print('type: ', type(ping_out))
print('getdefaultencoding: ', sys.getdefaultencoding())
print('locale: ', locale.getpreferredencoding())
print('stdout.encoding: ', sys.stdout.encoding)
print('stdin.encoding: ', sys.stdin.encoding)
```

Comment: Чем вам эта либа не нравиться https://github.com/romana/multi-ping ?

Comment: Требует root Note: ICMP packets can only be sent by processes with root privileges.

Comment: есть еще ping3 - https://github.com/kyan001/ping3/blob/master/README.md, но там тоже root права нужны

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
import locale
import subprocess
import platform

def ping(host):
    ping_str = "-n 1" if platform.system().lower() == "windows" else "-c 1"
    args = "ping " + " " + ping_str + " " + host
    con_out = subprocess.check_output(args, shell=True).decode('cp866')
    return con_out

ping_out = ping("google.com")
string = str(ping_out)
print('s', string)
print('encoded ', string.encode('utf8'))
print('type: ', type(ping_out))
print('getdefaultencoding: ', sys.getdefaultencoding())
print('locale: ', locale.getpreferredencoding())
print('stdout.encoding: ', sys.stdout.encoding)
print('stdin.encoding: ', sys.stdin.encoding)
```