# Ping ip из листа и запись их в файл

Tags: python, windows, list, ip, ping

Мне нужно сделать программу , которая в себя включает создание листа ip , пингует их всех и выводит всё в файл (ip и результаты комманды Ping) На windows , python.
Примерный код для создания листа:

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1
d = 1

f1 = open('file.txt','w')
f1.write("")
f1.close()
while True:
    if a < 256:
        j = print(d,c,b,a,sep='.')
        j
        a = a + 1
        f1 = open('file.txt','a')
        f1.write(str(d))
        f1.close()
        f1 = open('file.txt','a')
        f1.write(".")
        f1.close()
        f1 = open('file.txt','a')
        f1.write(str(c))
        f1.close()
        f1 = open('file.txt','a')
        f1.write(".")
        f1.close()
        f1 = open('file.txt','a')
        f1.write(str(b))
        f1.close()
        f1 = open('file.txt','a')
        f1.write(".")
        f1.close()
        f1 = open('file.txt','a')
        f1.write(str(a))
        f1.close()
        f1 = open('file.txt','a')
        f1.write("\n")
        f1.close()
        #print(s)
    if a == 256:
        b = b + 1
        a = 1
    if b == 256:
        b = 1
        c = c + 1
    if c == 256:
        c = 1
        d = d + 1
    if c == 255:
        d = d + 1
        c = 1
    if d == 255:
        if c == 255 and b == 255 and a == 255:
            print("finished")
            break
```

Как сделать так чтобы программа пинговала все IP из листа и записывала в файл результат ?

Comment: и в чем проблема? или вы просто похвастаться?

Comment: как сделать так чтобы она пинговала ? Она просто делает лист , а мне нужно , что бы она ещё и пинг делала.

Comment: вы для начала погуглите и что-то попробуйте. здесь с проблемами помогают разобраться, а не код за вас пишут.

Comment: чтото типа `os.system('ping ...)`

Comment: я пытался поискать , но давали только под линукс , а я в питоне не так давно , поэтому не смог переписать всё для винды.

Comment: https://yandex.ru/search/?text=python%20windows%20ping&clid=2261451&banerid=0899050204%3ASW-488adf45b4c5&win=280&lr=219

Comment: просто пинговать я умею , мне запись в файл самого результата нужно

Comment: то есть вы строку в файл записать не умеете?

Comment: мне не саму комманду ping записать надо , а то что она выводит . Записывать в файл я знаю как.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/902545/Вызов-системного-ping-в-python-и-обработка-его-вывода